# Firebase Cloud Notifications in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase-realtime-database

Is that working to make an Chrome Extension that can send Notifications to the user with getting the Informations from Firebase Cloud Service?

I will have an Extension, that i can send users informations with that have installed my extension on all Pages if the have Chrome opened...

Is there any tutorial? I cannot find anything about chrome extensions and firebase

Answer (score 1):

I used [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client) with some differences with FCM. On extension side I made all by this tutorial, on the server-side - by FCM tutuorial. It works, <strike>but at current time messages saved at FCM while browser is shut down don't come after browser open, looking for a bug.</strike>

---

Yes, it wouldn't save messages while browser is shut down.

> As long as Chrome is running, even if the extension or app is not running, it is woken up to deliver a message.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial in the link of the previous answer is now deprecated. "As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM.." [Learn more here.](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client)

Now, you can implement Firebase Cloud Messaging to your Javascript project with this tutorial, [See here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)